# How to change the error message of a TextBox validator when TextMode is set to number

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a TextBot control in my page and its TextMode property is set to Number.

Now what I need is to change the eror message when user inputs an invalid value. Which is as default:

"You must enter a valid value."

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbPrice" TextMode="Number" CssClass="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 2):

`TextMode` doesn't have Number option. I know you see the option with intellisense but see this URL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode(v=vs.110).aspx

It can only have `MultiLine`, `SingleLine` or `Password`. To get validation you are expecting you can use a `CompareValidator` as mentioned below which will show the message if you enter anything other than numbers.

```
<asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ID="valNumber" ControlToValidate="tbPrice" Type="Integer" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="You must enter a valid value." />
```

You can also use `AjaxControlToolkit` control `FilteredTextBox`. Which will not allow you to type anything else but number.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx

The other option you have is to restrict user to only enter numbers. See below link:

[How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for reply @Adarsh. But for me TextMode=Number works perfectly well. What I needed was to be able to change its warning essage. I can achieve that by using a CompareValidator but I rather learn the other way. :)

Comment: So you can't type anything other than number in the textbox or it shows the error msg after submitting?

Comment: I can type non-numeric values but it shows a message like Tooltip when I try to submit and stops postback, just before postback, which means client side.